# Add clickable icon to inline form bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to add a **clickable** current location button after (or in if possible) a the first input box. I'm having trouble appending it after the input box and not having a line break before the next input box. I've seen examples for input boxes but not forms.

```
<form class="form-inline" id="get-directions-form">


    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="start">
    <span class="input-group-btn"><img class="current-location-marker" src="http://imgur.com/pGM46FY.png"></span>

    <label> End </label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="end">

  <input class="btn btn-primary" id="submit-button" type='submit'></input>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
<form class="form-inline" id="get-directions-form">
<span class="textbox" style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px;">
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="start" style="border: none; padding-bottom: 5px;">
<img class="current-location-marker" src="http://imgur.com/pGM46FY.png" style="height: 32px;">
</span>

<label> End </label>
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="end">
<input class="btn btn-primary" id="submit-button" type='submit'></input>
</form>
```

I put the textbox and the image inside a span that was styled to look like a textbox.